# Nonstandard time zones and set hours

Tags: php

We have an hourly timetable that allows our staff to book each hour by their local time which are then saved as UTC.

The issue with this is some staff have non-standard time zones that have offsets of :30 such as some time zones in Australia which allows them to book slots over other slots.

What would be the best practice to prevent this from happening? I was thinking maybe altering it so that the booking page adds on half an hour to each hour for these specific timezones.

Comment: Are they really non-standard? http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php

Comment: By standard I mean HH:00 offset and non-standard asin HH:30 offset.

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/North');
$minute = date('i', strtotime('midnight UTC'));

would that be a good method?

Comment: half-hour offsets are perfectly standard, and it's perfectly straightforward converting tines in any of those timezones to UST using DateTime objects

Comment: I know that, but I can't use select input with 00:00 to 23:00. Would the best solution to have 00:$minute to 23:$minute?

Comment: Why can't you select input with 00:00 to 23:59? As long as you have a timezone select to go with each time, I don't understand what your issue is!